# Problem with Time Series Data - Negative Increase and Long Pause

Tags: matlab, time-series, data-analysis

I'm trying to solve two problems from Time Series data in Matlab.

```
Data = [1000 2000 3000 2500 4000 5000  9000 10000 11000 10500 12000 18000 19000 18500 20000 21000 22000 23000 24000 25000];
```

Write a function to find negative increase, e.g., `1000, 2000 3000, 2500, 4000, 5000, 9000`. Once we find the number, we need to shift all future times up, like `2500 -> 4000, and 4000 -> 5000`…

Write a function to identify long pause, e.g., `1000, 2000, 3000, 2500 4000, 5000,  9000, 10000, 11000, 10500, 12000, 18000`. After Identifying the number, we need to remember all pauses for padding with `nan`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. So you are trying to solve this problems (homework). What have you done so far? Where are you failing? Please read [ask]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.